# C# report viewer: Control with type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' cannot be handled by layout

Tags: c#, reportviewer, ext.net

I want to display a report in a panel like this :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server" ></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
    <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="800" Layout="FitLayout">
            <Content>
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="true" Width="100%"
                    OnInit="ReportViewer1_Init"
                    Font-Names="Verdana" SizeToReportContent="true"
                    ShowExportControls="true" ShowPrintButton="true" ShowBackButton="false" ShowFindControls="false"
                    ProcessingMode="Remote" Height="800px" ZoomMode="PageWidth">
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            </Content>
        </ext:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

But I get this error:

> > Control with type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' cannot be handled by layout

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by removing `Layout="FitLayout"` from `ext:Panel` properties